# Monodevelop libs/ folder

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, libs

I have a .jar file from github and have been asked to place it in my Android app’s libs/ folder. I am using MonoDevelop for Android, and I cannot see a libs/ folder anywhere. I see that in Eclipse, under options, a path can be added for .jar files. Is there the same thing for MonoDevelop? Can I please have some help to set this .jar file up correctly?

**EDIT**

Here is the jar I am wanting to use: http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/ I am after some help to please set this up for MonoDevelop for Android.

Comment: Eclipse is Java based, `libs/` folder is where normal Java JAR files go. Have not heard of MonoDevelop using Java JARS integrated into a project setting, sounds like you need to port it over for usage within the Mono environment...i.e. port the code to nearest equivalent suitable for mono..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

The `libs/` folder is where normal Java JAR files go under Eclipse which is for Java targetting Android platform. You will have to translate the Java code to the equivalent C# for usage by the Mono environment for Android.

That's called *porting*, if that does not help, try looking for a similar library out there.